# Correct way to initialize a map and delete in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, dictionary

I am trying to create a static map declared in the constructor of my class.
This map is to be initialized and filled with data in one method and free'd in another method.
Is this the correct way to do it?

```
using namespace std;
#include <map>

struct a {
     string b;
     string c;
}

class aClass:public myClass
 {
 public:
      aClass();
      virtual ~aClass();

 private: 
      map<string, a> myMap;
      void method(int a);
      void amethod(int b);
 }
 void aClass::method(int a)
 {
      myMap = new map<string, a>;
      // Addition of elements;
 }
 void aClass::amethod(int b)
 {
      // retrival of elements
      myMap.clear();
      delete myMap;
 }
```

Comment: In your code, the `myMap` is not `static`. What do you actually mean by "static"?

Comment: Why do you think you need to new up a map and delete it later? Just hold a map by value, and call clear() on it at the appropriate times.

Comment: I doubt you meant to include the [sli] tag.  I edited your post to include the [stl] tag instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  map<string, a> myMap;
  ....
  myMap = new map<string, a>;
```

Here `myMap` is not a pointer, so the initialization with `new` is incorrect. Perhaps you are looking for:

```
  myMap = map<string,a>();
```

to copy into `myMap` a *default initialized* map.

Note that you don't need (and in fact can't) `delete myMap`, as is not a pointer. It's a member variable, and the compiler will take care of automatically destroying it when your class is destroyed.

Comment: @snihalani: You don't free it, its not a pointer... perhaps all you want is to change `myMap` to be `map<string,a>*`?

Comment: @snihalani you don't free it, C++ will free it when the containing `aClass` is destroyed

Comment: This will be used multiple times, about 200 times, there are no issues with the correct ness of this code, right?

Comment: @snihalani: There are no issues, however reinitializing the map in `method` seems pointless as it _presumably_ has already been cleaned.

Answer (score 4):

```
void aClass::method(int a)
{
  myMap.clear();  // ensure it starts off empty
  // Addition of elements;
}
void aClass::amethod(int b)
{
  // retrival of elements
  myMap.clear();  // maybe not necessary
}
```

The object `myMap` already exists inside an instance of `aClass` and is constructed when its containing instance is constructed. You don't need to use `new` to create it, that's a Java and C# feature, where variables are just references to some instance on the heap and everything is garbage-collected. In C++ it's easier to make data members a value rather than a pointer or reference to some other object.